# Werkzeug AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'InteractiveInterpreter'

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

Using Flask (0.8) and Werkzeug (0.8.1) when attempting to run code with `app.run(debug=True)` I get the below described error. There are no errors when using `app.run()`

The error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "code2.py", line 9, in <module>
    app.run(debug=True)
File "/<snip>/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.8-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 703, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
File "/<snip>/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/serving.py", line 587, in run_simple
    from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication
File "/<snip>/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/debug/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from werkzeug.debug.tbtools import get_current_traceback, render_console_html
File "/<snip>/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/debug/tbtools.py", line 19, in <module>
    from werkzeug.debug.console import Console
File "/<snip>/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/debug/console.py", line 144, in <module>
    class _InteractiveConsole(code.InteractiveInterpreter):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'InteractiveInterpreter'
```

The code (code.py)

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/news/')
def news():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Steps taken to recreate the error

```
$ cd <project directory>
$ . env/bin/activate # Activates virtuanlenv environment (see below for packages)
$ python code.py
```

Contents of my env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (versions of various library used) via virtualenv

```
Flask-0.8-py2.7.egg
Jinja2-2.6-py2.7.egg
pip-1.0.2-py2.7.egg
setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
Werkzeug-0.8.1-py2.7.egg
```

Things I have tried to solve this problem so far, that have not helped (unfortunately)

- Extensive googling/SO searching
- Heavy simplification of my code
- Deleting created virtualenv and all libraries and reinstallation via easy_install

The strange thing here is that last night, this code worked fine. This morning, without changing anything (that I'm aware of) the code failed to properly run.

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The problem is that you have named your module `code.py`. `code` is a built in Python module that werkzeug uses (https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html).

To fix the problem, rename your `code.py` to something else, and make sure you delete the `code.pyc` file.

Comment: When Alexander Graham Bell invented the telephone he had three missed calls from @codeape

Answer (score 0):

Solution to your problem is is your filename; don't name your python file name as `code.py`, `main.py`, `Flask.py`, `os.py`, `system.py`.
Instead, you can use `code1.py` or something.