# Why my import for scapy doesn't work in python 3.8?

Tags: python, import, scapy, python-3.8

I tried do build a program that pings a website and print the answer. I expected that it'll ping google.com, but instead in the 1st line I get Attribute Error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Magshimim\Networks Programming\Lesson 06\Homework\Solution\code.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scapy.all import *
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\scapy\all.py", line 35, in <module>
    from scapy.autorun import *
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\scapy\autorun.py", line 29, in <module>
    class ScapyAutorunInterpreter(code.InteractiveInterpreter):
AttributeError: module 'code' has no attribute 'InteractiveInterpreter'
```

So far, I tried to import the scapy module using: `from scapy.all import *`, `import scapy` and `from scapy import *`

My code:

```
from scapy.all import *
fullmsg = Ether() / IP(dst='google.com') / ICMP()
ans = srp1(fullmsg, verbose=0)
print(ans.show())
```

Comment: Can you post the full error? What OS are you using? If you use a virtualenv, do you see the same error?

Comment: Maybe the cause is the name of your module. Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880827/werkzeug-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-interactiveinterprete)

Comment: @RossJacobs - I use windows. I don't exactly know what is it virtualenv.

Comment: Just rename your file. `code.py` is a poor name anyways, since any Python script will contain code. Rename it to `google_ping.py` or something.