# How to import a file in python?

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

How to access models/usrs from resources/user

```
├───models
|   └───user.py
├───resources
|   └───user.py
```

First I import it like this one:

```
from code.models.user import UserModel
```

But I got a compile-time error:

```
`Cannot find reference 'models' in 'code.py'`
```

And I tried another way like this one:

```
from ..models.user import UserModel
```

But I got a runtime error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

And I added **init**.py in both files but still doesn't work.

[image]

And also I tried these solutions but they don't fix my issue, please help me

Comment: You likely need an `__init__.py` file in the models and resources folders.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And finally, I fix my issue:

As @Little Bamboo said: I used sys concept for the import like below:

```
import sys    
sys.path.append("D:\\Projects\\Python\\UdemyProjects\\SixSimplifyingTwo")    
from mycode.models.userone import UserModel
```

But that was not all, some of my files had the same names and I changed the names of the files.

And also I had a folder called code, and from the below link I understood that code is a built-in Python module and I changed the code folder name.

[Werkzeug AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'InteractiveInterpreter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880827/werkzeug-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-interactiveinterprete)

Comment: Can you mark my answer as correct?  Thank you!  Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Add the models and resources directories to your $PYTHONPATH or use sys.path:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/you/want/to/add
```

Or:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/project-name/models")
```

Or add "__ init__.py" to code directory:

```
from code.models import user
```

Comment: Thank you @Little Bamboo,

First) I don't try the first one

Second) `import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "D:\Projects\Python\UdemyProjects\SixSimplifying\code\models")
import user`
I got this error:
`SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 18-21: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`

Third) I got this error: `Cannot find reference 'models' in 'code.py' `
Can you give more detailed advice?

Comment: This is because the string you're using sees the back slashes as escape characters.  I believe you can just add the letter 'r' just before your path.  Such as sys.path.insert(0, r"D:\Projects\Python\UdemyProjects\SixSimplifying\code\models")

Comment: You can also change all of your backslashes to forward slashes as well.

Comment: I added like this one
`import sys
sys.path.insert(0, r"D:/Projects/Python/UdemyProjects/SixSimplifying/code/models")
import user`
but now I got this error:
`python: can't open file 'D:\Projects\Python\UdemyProjects\SixSimplifying\code\Test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`